# Is expect code going to through error if i reboot remote machine?

Tags: tcl, expect

i am not sure what will happen so i am asking this question and also because i didn't tested this.i have a function send command which sends commands to remote machine and  it works fine for normal commands but what if it sends command for reboot like below.

```
sendcommand reload

expect -re "$prompt"
send -- "exit"
expect eof
```

i mean after reload how would the rest of the script going to excecute or it will thorugh some error or it will work fine? please guide.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Not really all that much to do with Tcl or Expect here that you don't already know…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly how you ask for the reboot to be done. Rebooting *may* be done by asking the system to restart, and the time to process that might allow you to exit. Or it might not; there's a race condition. You certainly need to drop the network connection though; when the OS comes back, it won't recognize it and you'll get a forced connection reset (if not before).

Or you could ask it to reboot a couple of seconds in the future (I forget the exact syntax for this) to give yourself time to disconnect. Some individual research and experimentation is likely to be needed; VMs are good for this as they restart much more rapidly…